# Unable to locate package 'file'

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a Docker image and it used to work fine until now. But, when I try to rebuild, it cannot locate the package `file` anymore.

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
...
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install file -y
...
```

The error message is as follows:

```
E: Unable to locate package file
ERROR: Service 'service' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install file' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Does anyone have an idea where the problem might be?

Comment: @mook765 As it turns out from UrmLmn's answer, this not a duplicate of that question and the *file* package is not provided by the universe repository anyway, so no one should have closed voted this question for that reason and all three close voters should retract their close votes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594987/how-to-force-docker-for-a-clean-build-of-an-image

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with `apt-get update` being cached by Docker. After building the Dockerfile with the `--no-cache` option, the file package could be installed. Can't tell where exactly the problem might have been.